# How to use ADB for generating Multitouch event like pinch in Android?

Tags: android, android-source

I want to generate input event for multitouch (pinch)in Android via ADB/command line.

Now I am able to genertate a touchcreen swipe event using below command

```
# input touchscreen swipe 87 230 1000 300 100
```

Edit :1

I need to know how to generate Multitouch event via command line using adb shell in Android device(just like above command to trigger touchscreen event);

[image]

Comment: Generate two swipe touch events going towards one another?

Comment: yes I tried that: Given two swipe events by two commands. But it is considered as two single events not as multi-touch

Comment: I found this, but I don't know if it's what you want.  https://github.com/openstf/minitouch

Comment: @cricket_007 minitouch is outstanding, and doesn't even require root. Thanks a lot.